# JPQL query - how to access a list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using jpql.

But I am having trouble creating a query because "tgDeclarationRglts" is a "List".

How can I access this list in the query to retrieve the "idDeclarationRglt" ?

Thank you !

The "DeclarationRglt" entity

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="DECREG_IDDECLARATION_RGLT", sequenceName="SID_DECLARATION_RGLT" , allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DECREG_IDDECLARATION_RGLT")
@Column(name="ID_DECLARATION_RGLT")
private long idDeclarationRglt;
```

The "LigneDipRec" entity

```
//bi-directional many-to-many association to TgDeclarationRglt
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name="TG_DIP_RECOUVREMENT"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_LIGNE_DIP_REC")
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_DECLARATION_RGLT")
        }
    )
private List<DeclarationRglt> tgDeclarationRglts;
```

Here is my query :

```
select distinct ta3.idTitre from LigneTa3 ta3, DeclarationRglt dec where ta3.tgDeclarationRglt.idDeclarationRglt =:idDecReg and dec.tcTypeDeclarationRglt.cdTypeDeclaration =:typeDec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to understand your question since your query is using an entity called LigneTa3 which you have not provided.

If I look purely at this part of your question:

> How can I access this list in the query to retrieve the
>   "idDeclarationRglt"?

then I think that all that you are looking for is something based on:

```
SELECT d.idDeclarationRglt
FROM LigneDipRec l JOIN l.tgDeclarationRglts d
```

That shows the general approach to accessing every element of a collection, you can always use that approach in a bigger query.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem  using the same approach as you :)